# How can i use @autowire in runnable spring boot

Tags: spring, mongodb, multithreading, autowired, runnable

I have few MongoTemplate and Repos and i need to call them using @Autowire in my runnable class that is being executed by exceutor class using multi threading, now the problem is that when i run the application my AutoWire for mongoTempelate and Repos returns null pointer exception.
Executor class:

```
@Component
public class MessageConsumer implements ConsumerSeekAware {
    @Autowired
    AlarmDataRepository alarmDataRepository;
    int assignableCores = ((Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()));
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(
            assignableCores > 1 ? assignableCores : 1
    );
    int counter = 0;
    List<String> uniqueRecords = new ArrayList<String>();
    @KafkaListener(topics = "teltonikaTest", groupId = "xyz")
    public void processMessages(@Payload List<String> payload, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) List<Integer> partitions, @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) List<Long> offsets) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, DecodeException {
        System.out.println("assignable resources are: " + assignableCores);
        log.info("Batch Size is: {}", payload.size());
        if(counter==0){
            log.info("Teletonica Packets Received!");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < payload.size(); i++) {
            log.info("processing message='{}' with partition off-set='{}'", payload.get(i), partitions.get(i) + " _" + offsets.get(i));
        }
        uniqueRecords = payload.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
        Runnable worker = new TeltonikaWorkerThread(uniqueRecords);
        executor.execute(worker);
        counter++;
    }
}

public class TeltonikaWorkerThread implements Runnable{
    List<String> records;
    List<CurrentDevice> currentDevices = new ArrayList<>();
    @Autowired
    CurrentDeviceRepository currentDeviceRepository;
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public TeltonikaWorkerThread(List<String> records) {
        this.records = records;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            processMessage();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  catch (DecodeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void processMessage() throws UnsupportedEncodingException,DecodeException {
        for(Object record : records){
            if(record!="0"){
                try{
                    int IMEILength = record.toString().indexOf("FF");
                    String IMEI = record.toString().substring(0,IMEILength);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should provide a reproducible example

Comment: Please post your code and what you have tried

Comment: code is added 
First class is where i receive packets from kafka and make them unique after that i pass the unique records to the TeltonikaWorker thread then from there right after my IMEI string defined in ProcessMessage i want to call my repo to execute query and get records on IMEI but unfortunately im not able to autowire my repo and it throws nullPointerException for that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem is about multiple beans and Spring doesn't know which one should be injected. There are several options here.

For example, you can use [`@Qualifier`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation based on the bean name or [`@Primary`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html) annotation.

If your problem is something else, please add an example to your question.